# OctoberCMS Javascript API AJAX call to a component function to update component's partial

Tags: javascript, ajax, octobercms

So I have the following file structure:

```
plugins/myname/pluginname/components/pluginname/default.htm
plugins/myname/pluginname/components/PluginName.php
```

default.htm acts as the partial of the component.
and I have the following JS API

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.request('onEverySecond', {
        update: {'@default.htm':'#rate-marquee'},
        complete: function() {
            console.log('Finished!');
        }
    })
}, 1000);
```

`onEverySecond` is a function in `PluginName.php` that updates a variable called `fx` thrown to `default.htm`.

At the front end the partial `default.htm` seems to be updated, but it refreshes the whole partial which is not what I want, it causes the marquee to replay again and again and only be able to show the first few piece of contents.
All I wanted is that the AJAX will update only the variable `fx` where the data is updated.

How can I achieve that?

EDIT 1:

Here is the partial markup:

```
{% set fx = __SELF__.fx %}
<marquee id="rate-marquee" name="rate-marquee" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
    <ul>
        {% for item in fx %}
            <li>
            {{ item.Item | trim('u')}}: {{ item.BID }} {% if item.Revalue == 0 %} <div class="arrow-up"></div> {% else %} <div class="arrow-down"></div> {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</marquee>
```

Additionally, here is the code in PluginName.php

```
public function onRun()
{
    $this->addJs('/plugins/SoyeggWebDevelopment/fxmarquee/assets/js/default.js');
    $this->updateFX();
}


public function onEverySecond()
{
    $this->updateFX();
}

public $fx;
```

So updateFX() works perfectly well too.

Comment: can you share partial markup and `fx` variable used.

Comment: @HardikSatasiya thanks for your repsonse. the variable was updated perfectly every second upon the marquee refreshes. However the whole marquee refreshes everytime so the marquee restarts the loop again and again. I updated the markup and please have a look, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here problem seems you are replacing `whole marquee` it causes to re-render it.

> To solve this we can just update portion inside `marquee`

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.request('onEverySecond', {        
        complete: function() {
            console.log('Finished!');
        }
    })
}, 1000);
```

> We don't do anything special here just a simple `ajax call`

to update portion of `marquee` we need to `assign id to it` and we define internal partial

```
<marquee id="rate-marquee" 
         name="rate-marquee" 
         onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
    <ul id='rate-marquee-inner'> <!-- <= here -->
      {% partial __SELF__ ~ '::_marquee_inner' %}        
    </ul>
</marquee>
```

> `_marquee_inner.htm` partila markup

```
{% set fx = __SELF__.fx %}
{% for item in fx %}
    <li>
    {{ item.Item | trim('u')}}: {{ item.BID }} {% if item.Revalue == 0 %} <div class="arrow-up"></div> {% else %} <div class="arrow-down"></div> {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

and to update that portion we just need to return markup array

```
function onEverySecond() {
    $this->updateFX();
    return ['#rate-marquee-inner' => $this->renderPartial('_marquee_inner.htm')];
}
```

> this will just `push new updated markup` to given id `#rate-marquee-inner` so now it will `just update inner portion of marquee` and `marquee` will not re-render.

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Thanks Hardik, now it returns error `The partial '_marquee_inner.htm' is not found.` showing the error happens in `default.htm`, so somehow `{% partial __SELF__ ~ '::_marquee_inner' %}` is not reading the partial that I already created. Couldn't see any typo

Comment: I figure it out. There are some changes in the code to be made:
cannot use `return ['#rate-marquee-inner' => $this->renderPartial('_marquee_inner.htm')];` it turns out to show only the code in `_marquee_inner.htm` without even the layout. and it also needs `@` before the htm to reference component's partial.
secondly, I delete the above mentioned line and do the update in js instead so it only update the `ul`
`update: {'@_marquee_inner.htm':'#rate-marquee-inner'},`